# malloc large memory never returns NULL

Tags: malloc, free

when I run this, it seems to have no problem with keep allocating memory with cnt going over thousands. I don't understand why -- aren't I supposed to get a NULL at some point? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
    long C = pow(10, 9);
    int cnt = 0;
    int conversion = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
    int *p;
    while (1)
    {
        p = (int *)malloc(C * sizeof(int));
        if (p != NULL)
            cnt++;
        else break;
        if (cnt % 10 == 0)
            printf("number of successful malloc is %d with %ld Mb\n", cnt, cnt * C / conversion);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're allocating *virtual* memory. On a 64-bit OS, virtual memory is available in almost unlimited supply.

Comment: Thanks! So I will never get a seg fault unless I try to actually access these memory?

Comment: You might get a segfault if the operating system winds up needing more backed memory than it has.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this on Linux? Linux has a highly surprising feature known as [overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html). It doesn't actually allocate memory when you call malloc(), but rather when you actually **use** that memory. malloc() will happily let you allocate as much memory as your heart desires, never returning a NULL pointer.

It's only when you actually access the memory that Linux takes you seriously and goes out searching for free memory to give you. Of course there may not actually be enough memory to meet the promise it gave your program. You say, "Give me 8GB," and malloc() says, "Sure." Then you try to write to your pointer and Linux says, "Oops! I lied. How bout I just kill off processes (probably yours) until I I free up enough memory?"

Comment: I am running on Mac OS X Snow leopard. Is this the case as well?